# Racket list results if no index element is present

Tags: racket

I am trying to modify this program in Racket such that if no index element is present in this list, it should return `#f`. A little guidance is helpful.
Thanks in advance

```
#lang racket
(define get-nth
  (lambda (index lst)
    (let loop ((index index) (my-list lst))
      (cond ((null? my-list) lst)
            ((= index 0) (car my-list))
            (else (loop (- index 1) (cdr my-list)))))))

(get-nth 4 '(a b))
```

`;#f`

Comment: http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs200-spring2003/problem-sets/ps7/listprocs.ss

Answer (score 1):

Just return `#f` instead of the list...

```
(define get-nth
  (lambda (index lst)
    (let loop ((index index) (my-list lst))
      (cond ((null? my-list) #f)
            ((= index 0) (car my-list))
            (else (loop (- index 1) (cdr my-list)))))))
```

Because now we don't have to "remember" the original input list, we can simplify things and eliminate the named `let`, like this:

```
(define get-nth
  (lambda (index lst)
    (cond ((null? lst) #f)
          ((= index 0) (car lst))
          (else (get-nth (- index 1) (cdr lst))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can forget about the `let loop` and instead use tail-recursion. The list will be empty if you're trying to get to an index longer than the lenght of the list, therefore, when the list is empty, return `false`.

```
#lang racket
(define get-nth
  (lambda (index lst)
      (cond 
        ((empty? lst) #f)
        ((= index 0) (car lst))
        (else (get-nth (- index 1) (cdr lst))))))
```